# How can I know the IP address of my Wifi Camera?

Tags: ip-address, ip-camera

I am new with wifi camera. I have a wifi camera, with a built in wifi. I turn on the camera and connect my Laptop to the camera's wifi, so it is directly connected to the camera. I check the IP configuration of my laptop and found the IP address of my laptop and the gateway. **How can I know the IP address of the camera?** Is the gateway address the camera's IP address, since it is **dicrectly** connected to the laptop?

Comment: Sorry, that's not a programming question and as such it is off-topic here. Check out e.g. superuser.com. With the little info you provide, there is probably just as small a chance to get useful answers, so describe a bit more what you have and what you did.

Comment: which OS are you running on your laptop? 
run nmap.

Answer (score 0):

what make & model is the camera? most manufacturers have a default IP address for their cameras. for instance, axis cameras will be found at 192.168.0.90 unless a DHCP server tells it otherwise. the camera will then accept whatever it is assigned.